# How to correctly get the value returned from a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am using nodejs + Express for my backend service.

I have a authenHandler.js file to help authentication with sequelize:

```
module.exports = {
  isAuthenticated: function(data) {
    models.Users.find(data)
      .then(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

When I am using this helper function in app.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        // process to retrieve data
        var isAuthenticated = authProvider.isAuthenticated(data);
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            console.log("auth passed.");
            next();
        } else {
            var err = new Error(authenticationException);
            err.status = 403;
            next(err);
        }
    }
})
```

This always goes to the else statement because the isAuthenticated print line always return undefined. Looks like the promise returned the value after the if-else statement is called.

I am not exactly sure how to connect the authenHandler.js and the app.js. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: have u use require('authenHandler.js') yet?

Comment: See "Promise gotchas" in the duplicate.

Comment: You can use isAuthenticated function as middleware by keeping same parameter req, res and next in the isAuthenticated function and can process to retrieve date itself in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to return the promise

```
isAuthenticated: function(data) {
    return models.Users.find(data)
      .then(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
```

and then consume the promise

```
authProvider.isAuthenticated(data)
.then((result =>{
var isAuthenticated = result;
  console.log(isAuthenticated);
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            console.log("auth passed.");
            next();
        } else {
            var err = new Error(authenticationException);
            err.status = 403;
            next(err);
        }
}))
```

Comment: What if in isAuthenticated function, I also have a check:
if (!data) { return false;}
before I call the sequelize promise? How should I wrap the validation of data into a promise?
Thanks!

Comment: and what exactly does result => {} mean? I don't think its a valid syntax in nodejs?

Comment: ()=>{} is es6 arrow function, which can be written as 'function(){}' in older versions. node supports arrow functions. (see version compatibility) .
Didn't understand your first question.

Answer (score 1):

your app.js is wrong, isAuthenticated returns promise not return bool

you need to modify app.js like this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

        // process to retrieve data
        authProvider.isAuthenticated(data)
          .then(function(isAuthenticated) {
            if (isAuthenticated) {
              console.log("auth passed.");
              next();
            }
            else {
              var err = new Error(authenticationException);
              err.status = 403;
              next(err);
            }
          });
    }
})
```

Comment: Looks like I also need to change authProvider.isAuthenticated() to make it return promise? How should I do that?

Comment: @jamesdeath123  You should add "return" before models.Users.xxxxx