# Return promise and content (can be many)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to node.js and trying to work my way around promises. I am trying to read contents from a file, return a promise, and contents of the file. I was so far able to read the contents of the file and print them on my console, and return a promise. I want return the contents of the file too.

Here is my code so far.

```
function() {
return fs.exists(listFile).then(function (exists) {
    if(exists) {
        return fs.readFile(listFile).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.toString());
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('failed to read from the file', error);
        });
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Error checking existence', err)
});
};
```

Comment: Answer to similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39761387/4175944

Comment: Are you using Bluebird?  `fs.exists()` doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly get the value returned from a promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761302/how-to-correctly-get-the-value-returned-from-a-promise)

Comment: @jessegavin I am using mz. I think it does use Bluebird

Answer (score 1):

fs.readFile(listFile) returns a promise. That is why you can chain the ".then()" method behind it. There isn't really anything you can return at this point. Also it would be returned to the callback function that you passed to ".then" on the second line.

To access the contents of the file you would need to call another function with the contents of the file right where you are printing it to the console.

```
function() {
return fs.exists(listFile).then(function (exists) {
    if(exists) {
        fs.readFile(listFile).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.toString());
            handleFileContents(response.toString());
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('failed to read from the file', error);
        });
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Error checking existence', err)
});
};

function handleFileContents(content) {
    // ... handling here
}
```

Comment: @baao, OP is using `mz/fs` which does return promises.

Comment: @Lenco how does this solve my problem of having to return both content and a promise? I will need the file content passed to another promise.

Comment: But the promise WILL have the content in the future, there is no way you can get both of them at the same time. That's the principle of asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `return` the contents of the file themselves, they are retrieved asynchronously. All you can do is return a promise *for* the contents:

```
function readExistingFile(listFile) {
    return fs.exists(listFile).then(function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
            return fs.readFile(listFile).then(function(response) {
                var contents = response.toString();
                console.log(contents);
                return contents;
 //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error('failed to read from the file', error);
                return "";
            });
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Error checking existence', err)
        return "";
    });
}
```

Use it like

```
readExistingFile("…").then(function(contentsOrEmpty) {
    console.log(contentsOrEmpty);
});
```

---

Btw, [using `fs.exists` like you did is an antipattern](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback), and it's deprecated in general. Omit it and just catch the error from a nonexisting file:

```
function readExistingFile(listFile) {
    return fs.readFile(listFile).then(function(response) {
        return response.toString();
    }, function(error) {
        if (error.code == "ENOENT") { // did not exist
            // …
        } else {
            console.error('failed to read from the file', error);
        }
        return "";
    });
}
```